# Different outputs in R when clicked RUN and SOURCE(What is the difference between RUN and SOURCE tab in Rstudio))

Tags: r, rstudio

I just started learning R.I am calculating roots of quadratic equations using conditional statements. Heres my code

```
a <- readline(prompt= "Enter value of a:")
b <- readline(prompt= "Enter value of b:")
c <- readline(prompt= "Enter value of c:")
a <- as.numeric(a)
b <- as.numeric(b)
c <- as.numeric(c)
D <-(b^2-4*a*c)
if (D>0) {
x_1 <- (-b+sqrt(D))/(2*a)  
x_2 <- (-b-sqrt(D))/(2*a)        
result <- (c(x_1 ,x_2 )) 
result
}else if(D==0){  
x <- rep((-b)/(2*a),2)  
}else if(D<0){
  x_1 <- (-b)/(2*a)+(sqrt(abs(D)))/(2*a)*(1i)  
  x_2 <- (-b)/(2*a)-(sqrt(abs(D)))/(2*a)*(1i)   
  result <- (c(x_1 ,x_2 )) 
  result
}
```

When I press run(ctrl+A) it says

Error in 4 * a : non-numeric argument to binary operator

When I press source it runs my code and asks me to enter value of a,b,c and when I input values then press enters it returns me this

```
> a <- readline(prompt= "Enter value of a:")
Enter value of a:3

> b <- readline(prompt= "Enter value of b:")
Enter value of b:5

> c <- readline(prompt= "Enter value of c:")
Enter value of c:3

> a <- as.numeric(a)

> b <- as.numeric(b)

> c <- as.numeric(c)

> D <-(b^2-4*a*c)

> if (D>0){                       #why this came ?
+   x_1 <- (-b+sqrt(D))/(2*a)  
+   x_2 <- (-b-sqrt(D))/(2*a)        
+   result <- (c(x_1 ,x_2 )) 
+   result
+ }else if(D==0){  
+   x < .... [TRUNCATED]           #till here
[1] -0.8333333+0.5527708i -0.8333333-0.5527708i
>
```

And what is the difference in clicking run and source. Why different outputs I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `run` is like copy-pasting the selected lines into the console, or like typing all of the selected text (including newlines etc) into the console.
- `source` is saving the selected text into a files and then running the `source` command on that file. To see exactly what `source` does see its documentation (`?source`).

Running the commands is often easier but has some disadvantages: it doesn't stop when an error occurs or when input is asked. In this case the first `readline` asks for input. It receives that input, namely the next line in the file.

Small example:

```
a <- readline(prompt = "a: ")
print(a)
print(a)
```

When running this (CRTL-A CRTL-ENTER), I see the following in the console:

```
> a <- readline(prompt = "a: ")
a: print(a)
> print(a)
[1] "print(a)"
```

As you can see, the second line `print(a)` is used as input. Therefore, `a` has the value `print(a)`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you help me in my code ? Why doesn't it shows just answer? It shows all if block  in output screen. Is it usual?

Comment: @Damandeep Yes and no. The source button in R Studio has a drop down menu. When you choose `Source with Echo` you get what you are seeing. It echos the commands it is running, truncating the command when too long. The regular `source` (also in the menu; or use the command `source("your_r_script.R")`) wouldn't show anything. You should use a `print(results)` to get output (or use `format` or `cat` for formatted output).